# How can I safely rollback specific upgrades?

Tags: apt, nvidia, upgrade, 22.04, unattended-upgrades

I am currently dealing with gpu crashes which I believe have been caused by a bunch of packages that were upgraded this morning on my machine. Here's the history.log entries for this morning.

I am new to linux, though fairly technical, and I am simply not sure how to focus on which elements from this list to roll back in order to find ways to roll them back. Ideally I'd be able to revert these to the versions that were removed, and, I assume, block them from being reinstalled.

I suspect there's probably a straightforward way, I simply don't know it.

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 lts with proprietary nvidia drivers.

```
 Start-Date: 2024-02-16  06:50:33
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Install: linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-18-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-18.18~22.04.1, automatic), linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-18:amd64 (6.5.0-18.18~22.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-6.5.0-18-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-18.18~22.04.1, automatic), linux-image-6.5.0-18-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-18.18~22.04.1, automatic), linux-headers-6.5.0-18-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-18.18~22.04.1, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (6.5.0.17.17~22.04.9, 6.5.0.18.18~22.04.10), linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (6.5.0.17.17~22.04.9, 6.5.0.18.18~22.04.10), linux-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (6.5.0.17.17~22.04.9, 6.5.0.18.18~22.04.10)
End-Date: 2024-02-16  06:50:58

 Start-Date: 2024-02-16  06:51:00
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: passwd:amd64 (1:4.8.1-2ubuntu2.1, 1:4.8.1-2ubuntu2.2)
End-Date: 2024-02-16  06:51:01

Start-Date: 2024-02-16  06:51:04
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Install: linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.5.0-18-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-18.18~22.04.1, automatic), linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.5.0-18-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-18.18~22.04.1, automatic), linux-signatures-nvidia-6.5.0-18-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-18.18~22.04.1, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-modules-nvidia-535-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (6.5.0-17.17~22.04.1+1, 6.5.0-18.18~22.04.1)
End-Date: 2024-02-16  06:51:21

Start-Date: 2024-02-16  06:51:24
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: login:amd64 (1:4.8.1-2ubuntu2.1, 1:4.8.1-2ubuntu2.2)
End-Date: 2024-02-16  06:51:24

Start-Date: 2024-02-16  06:51:27
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.5.0-15-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-15.15~22.04.1+1), linux-signatures-nvidia-6.5.0-15-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-15.15~22.04.1+1), linux-image-6.5.0-15-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-15.15~22.04.1)
End-Date: 2024-02-16  06:51:32

Start-Date: 2024-02-16  06:51:35
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-15-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-15.15~22.04.1), linux-modules-6.5.0-15-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-15.15~22.04.1)
End-Date: 2024-02-16  06:51:35

Start-Date: 2024-02-16  06:51:38
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-headers-6.5.0-15-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-15.15~22.04.1)
End-Date: 2024-02-16  06:51:38

Start-Date: 2024-02-16  06:51:41
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.5.0-15-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-15.15~22.04.1+1)
End-Date: 2024-02-16  06:51:41

Start-Date: 2024-02-16  06:51:43
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-15:amd64 (6.5.0-15.15~22.04.1)
End-Date: 2024-02-16  06:51:44
```

Comment: There is no easy way to roll back updates unless you have previously installed something like timeshift. Barring that, you can go into synaptic, select a package, and look at properties/versions. Normally there is only a choice of the basic version delivered at install and the latest available. The n-1 version is not available. This is why something like timeshift is so valuable - for example, Debian just broke everybody's system that used nvidia, but all I had to do was roll back to the prior day's timeshift snapshot.